# Can I use setxxx function to get current state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get current state in a callback after await some async task.

I think this will only execute the setStateAction function and will not trigger component rendering or any other side effects.
Will this lead to unexpected issues? Or any better way to do it?

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  const update = useCallback(async () => {
    let currState;

    await something; // state may change while waiting for this task

    // get current state
    setState((prev) => {
      currState = prev;
      return prev;
    });

    console.log(currState)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div>{state}</div>
      <button onClick={update}>update</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: that's fine and (setState) will trigger the rendering. You can also omit the `useCallback` in favor of a simple plain (async) function. In this case you don't need `useCallback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a ref using `useRef()` and put value of state in ref before updating state. `useRef` changes are instant and it will not trigger component re-render.

```
const Comp = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState(1);
const stateBeforeUpdate = useRef();

const update = useCallback(async () => {
stateBeforeUpdate.current = state;

await something; // state may change while waiting for this task

// get current state, you can change state here and stateBeforeUpdate will still hold previous state even after re-render.
setState((prev) => {
  return prev;
});

console.log(stateBeforeUpdate.current)
}, [])

return (
<>
  <div>{state}</div>
  <button onClick={update}>update</button>
</>
);
};
```